# Rails: How to redirect all urls from previous model to the new model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I'm developing a sample app.
I have a model called `Doi`. Since it seems less intuitive, I renamed the model to `Destination`.

I'm stuck with one main issue: how to redirect all the urls that contained the old model `Doi` to the new model `Destination`.

Example:

```
    0.0.0.0:3000/<action_x>/dois/<action_y>
```

should automatically redirect to

```
    0.0.0.0:3000/<action_x>/destinations/<action_y>
```

In my routes.rb, I have used:

```
    match '/**/dois/**' => redirect('/**/destinations/**')
```

But it didn't work. What is the correct way to go about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with

```
match '/:before/dois/:after' => redirect('/%{before}/destinations/%{after}')
```

See more examples of dynamic redirection in the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection)

---

Another solution, more customisable, would be:

```
match '*before/dois/*after' => redirect {|params| "#{params[:before]}/destinations/#{params[:after]}" }
```

More help with wildcards also in the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing)

Comment: How can I make use of wildcards in routes ?
Supposing I don't necessarily have a 'before' or may be I have two there (ex: /something/someother/dois/after) ?

Comment: @harsha_g I've added another solution that may suits better.